# retrieving current drive letters in windows (from python)

Tags: python, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to list all the available drive letters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python)

What's the way to retrieve currently mounted drive list in Windows incl. Thumb drives, and mapped networks.

i currently do

```
    drives=[]
    for c in string.lowercase:
        if os.path.isdir(c+':'):
            drives.append(c+':')
```

which looks ugly, but is completely KISS proof :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\x00")
```

Comment: Here is a full working example based on Sanjaya's answer:
  
`import win32api  
def does_drive_exist(letter):  
    return (letter in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\x00"))  
print does_drive_exist("P:\\")`