# Get IP Adress from a connected Windows Network Share with Python

Tags: python, windows, networking

How can i manage to get the IP or path like \11.1.1.100\projects of a connected network share with a drive letter.
I only have the drive letter and want to get the IP of the Share with python. 
Many Thanks...
Sashmo

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the python equivalent, but [WNetGetConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453.aspx) will give you the UNC path mapped to the drive letter:

```
wchar_t szName[256];
DWORD chName = 256;
DWORD dwResult = WNetGetConnectionW(L"Z:", szName, &chName);
```

I'm sure there is a python module that wraps this functionality.  From the UNC path you can get the server name, and from that you can lookup its IP address.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
Throug this WNetGetConnectionW i came across win32net for python and that did the trick.

Comment: `win32wnet.WNetGetConnection('X:')`

Comment: Use this in combination with [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python) to do some useful stuff with drive mapping/unmapping (my current headache).