# How can I enumerate filesystems from Python?

Tags: python, windows, linux, filesystems

I'm using `os.statvfs` to find out the free space available on a volume -- in addition to querying free space for a particular path, I'd like to be able to iterate over all volumes.  I'm working on Linux at the moment, but ideally would like something which returns `["/", "/boot", "home"]` on Linux and `["C:\", "D:\"]` on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux how about parsing `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`? Or:

```
import commands

mount = commands.getoutput('mount -v')
lines = mount.split('\n')
points = map(lambda line: line.split()[2], lines)

print points
```

For Windows I found something like this:

```
import string
from ctypes import windll

def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_drives()
```

and this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
fso = Dispatch('scripting.filesystemobject')
for i in fso.Drives :
    print i
```

Try those, maybe they help.

Also this should help: [Is there a way to list all the available drive letters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python)