# Python: Accessing Windows mapped network drive with known URL, but unknown drive letter

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that can move and copy files on a remote Linux server. However, I can't assume that everyone running the script (on Windows) will have mapped this server to the same letter. Rather than prompting users for the correct letter, I want to simply access the server by its network URL, the one that the drive letter is mapped to. So, for instance, if I have mapped the server's URL

```
\\name-of-machine.site.company.com
```

To be drive S:\, I want to access, say, the file S:\var\SomeFile.txt in a drive-letter agnostic manner. I have looked around and the general recommendation seems to be to use UNC notation:

```
f = open(r"\\name-of-machine.site.company.com\var\SomeFile.txt", "w")
```

But if I try this, an IOError saying there is no such file or directory. If I try using the server's IP address instead (not the real address, but similar):

```
f = open(r"\\10.1.123.149\var\SomeFile.txt", "w")
```

I get, after a long pause, an IO Error: "invalid mode ('w') or filename". Why are these notations not working, and how can I access this server (ideally as if it were a local drive) by its URL?

Comment: The unc address should work--it works fine on my network.  But if you don't have the correct permissions, then you will get an IOError. Sounds like a permissions problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution, but you could just try all the drives?

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python):

```
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
print drives
```

Then you could use `os.path.exists()` on every drive:\var\SomeFile.txt until you find the right one.

Comment: That will work as a last resort. Though it does (probably safely) assume the user has mapped the server to something.

Comment: Where is the documentation for win32api?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32api.html), for example.

Comment: I may have to use this. Is there a way to check the address each letter is mapped to?

Answer (score 7):

Easy solution is to use forward slashes to specify the Universal Name Convention (UNC):

```
//HOST/share/path/to/file
```

Found this solution in another thread and felt it would be relevant here. See original thread below:

[Using Python, how can I access a shared folder on windows network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network)

Comment: even so, a thumbs up from here, it matched by qoogle query to the letter.
(and google brought me here so, thanks)

- also, this solution does in fact solve the problem here, and I cannot see how this question differs

Answer (score 0):

Try using the short name instead of the fully qualified name.  In you example that would be `\\name-of-machine\var\SomeFile.txt`.

Edit:

Okay, now I feel like a dummy -- hopefully you'll feel like one with me!  ;)

The machine name is `name-of-machine.site.company.com`, and the folder and file name is `\var\SomeFile.txt` -- what is the share name?  In other words, your path should be something like:

```
\\name-of-machine.site.company.com\share_name\var\SomeFile.txt
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. I never reference the machine via the short name; mapping it as a network drive needs the fully qualified name. The fully qualified name is also a valid URL on my company's intranet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reserve a drive letter for this task, and you have the privileges then you can run "net use ..." from python and then use that fixed drive letter to read/write files.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I don't want to worry about drive letters at all; isn't there some way to access the files on this server using the address I use to map the drive in the first place, rather than worry about arbitrary drive letters? Or do I have to do it via FTP or something? (Would that even work?)

Comment: There are countless other ways to access files on a linux server. You can use DAV, for example. http://www.ikeepincloud.com/en/python_library But really there are so many protocols and client libs that is would be hard to list them all. I have selected webdav as an example because it does exactly what you need, and it is easy to install.

Using windows networking is a nightmare anyway...