# How to connect to shared drive using server name instead of mapped drive letter

Tags: python

I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730025/python-accessing-windows-mapped-network-drive-with-known-url-but-unknown-drive) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169845/using-python-how-can-i-access-a-shared-folder-on-windows-network) but I'm still unable to connect to shared drive.

The disk is in the form of `company (\\server.name.company) (V:)`. This works:

```
open("V:\path\to\file.txt")
```

and this doesn't

```
open("\\server.name.company\path\to\file.txt")
```

I'm losing my mind because I believe I did the exact same thing as in linked answers, so I've also tried

```
open("//server.name.company/path/to/file.txt")
```

I've checked for server name typos, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What else could be the problem here?

Comment: It's probably that you don't specify which disk drive to go to... maybe? So the `V:` part goes first instead of the other locations.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this is ridiculous, but the preceeding `company` in `company (\\server.name.company) (V:)` had to be added to the path in this manner:

```
open("//server.name.company/company/path/to/file.txt")
```

I wonder why that is, but since that detail was omitted in linked answers I guess it has something to do with how my disk was mapped.