# Searching for a USB in Python is returning 'there is no disk in drive'

Tags: python, windows, os.path

I wrote up a function in Python that looks for a USB drive based on a key identifier file, however when called upon it returns 'There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive D:/' (which is an SD card reader) - is there a way to have it search drive letters based on drives that are 'ready'?

```
def FETCH_USBPATH():
    for USBPATH in ascii_uppercase:
        if os.path.exists('%s:\\File.ID' % USBPATH):
            USBPATH='%s:\\' % USBPATH
            print('USB is mounted to:', USBPATH)
            return USBPATH + ""
    return ""

USBdrive = FETCH_USBPATH()
while USBdrive == "":
    print('Please plug in USB & press any key to continue', end="")
    input()
    FlashDrive = FETCH_USBPATH()
```

Had a fix in cmd here however turned out command-prompt based didn't suit my needs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python to list available drive letters. I'm not sure if the method there will return a drive with no disk.

Comment: Richie's answer worked however that also returned D:// which is an 'empty' drive/

Comment: You can use ctypes to call [`SetThreadErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd553630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Setting the mode to `SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` should prevent CSRSS from showing the error box. Restore the old mode after you're done.

Comment: @eryksun - I am a coding newbie and would have zero idea on how to accomplish this, where would I get started?

Comment: @eryksun - '\\?\Volume{526c17d7-adb8-11e4-81da-806e6f6e6964}\

Comment: @eryksun - I have added your ctypes SetThreadedErrorMode section to my code - I will update the original post - it doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question. You may post your own answer if you like.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I needed to copy Eryksun's updated/edited code which did actually fix it, but thanks for deleting it before I got the chance to save what he did - can you please restore it temporarily?

Comment: @eryksun Can you please repost what you had added to the question, as an answer? Your code snippet works but I didn't save the project - went to retrieve it now to find Andrew had deleted it. Lovely.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, sorry I should have provided an answer, but I'm averse to posting an 'answer' that I cannot personally test. I first wanted feedback that it worked, but the OP misunderstood my comment. I had every intention to roll the edit back (and post an answer if it worked); I was just waiting for Julian to notify me.

Comment: @JulianWhite, you should be able to see the entire edit history by clicking on the link that shows the last edit time, so technically Andrew didn't delete anything.

Comment: Strange, I clicked that but all it managed to do was load my original question. I'm still newish here, as you can probably tell ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding 'ready' drives may be more trouble that it's worth for your needs. You can probably get away with just temporarily disabling the error message dialog box via [`SetThreadErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd553630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')

SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 1
SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX = 0x8000
SEM_FAIL = SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS

def FETCH_USBPATH():
    oldmode = ctypes.c_uint()
    kernel32.SetThreadErrorMode(SEM_FAIL, ctypes.byref(oldmode))
    try:
        for USBPATH in ascii_uppercase:
            if os.path.exists('%s:\\File.ID' % USBPATH):
                USBPATH = '%s:\\' % USBPATH
                print('USB is mounted to:', USBPATH)
                return USBPATH
        return ""
    finally:
        kernel32.SetThreadErrorMode(oldmode, ctypes.byref(oldmode))

USBdrive = FETCH_USBPATH()
while USBdrive == "":
    print('Please plug in our USB drive and '
          'press any key to continue...', end="")
    input()
    USBdrive = FETCH_USBPATH()
```

Comment: Ah you're a life saver mate - You're absolutely right, finding 'not-ready' drives and skipping them could use a hunk of time and programming that I frankly lack the time and skill for (coding is obviously not my area). Temp hiding it fixes it, it's nothing serious an error.