# Partition disk python

Tags: python, diskspace

I want to fetch all the local disks and their partitions then as a result return all the data like "total space, used space and free space". The problem is to check if the partition is exist then continue to end if not through error.

In the code below, my local disk has three partitions: C:\, D:\, F:\ . However, partition G:\ is not exist so it is hang then closed.

I am using Python 3.6 and Pycharm community.

```
def disk_usage(self):
        disks = ['C','D','F','G']
        for i in disks:
            total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(i+":\\")
            try:
                print("Drive " + i + " as follows:")
                print("==================")
                print("Total: %d GB" % (total // (2**30)))
                print("Used: %d GB" % (used // (2**30)))
                print("Free: %d GB" % (free // (2**30)))
                print("===========")
                print("")
            except GetoptError as err:
               print(err)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could see if the path exists before computing size:

```
p = i+":"+os.sep
if os.path.exists(p):
    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(p)
```

or catch the `OSError` exception

```
try:
   total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(i+":\\")
   ...
catch OSError:
    pass
```

As an aside, it would be a good idea to obtain that drives list dynamically too (see [Is there a way to list all the available drive letters in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-drive-letters-in-python)).

That probably still requires to check for existence / catch exception (disk not in drive of such) as explained above.