# python get a list of the currently working drives

Tags: python

I what to know how to get a list of working drives in python(Windows)

```
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
print drives
```

works but gets a list of all the posable drives i what a list of all the currently
plugged in/working drives

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to list all the available Windows' drives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-windows-drives)

Comment: use this answer `available_drives = ['%s:' % d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]`, you can also use your approach and filter for `os.path.exits(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code

```
available_drives = ['%s:' % d for d in string.ascii_uppercase if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
```

You can also use your approach and filter for `os.path.exits(..)`