# How to use prefix paths in a Python configuration file?

Tags: python, path, config, configparser

My python config file looks like this:

```
[PATHS]
source = Q:\data\Energy\Source
archive = Q:\data\Energy\Archive

[DB]
host= localhost
user = root
passwd = *****
database= *****
```

Now I have a problem with my path, the location (actually the letter) changes every now and then because I'm making use of network drives. The network drives choses a location/letter based on its availability. So If `X` is not available for example, the network drive uses `Y` etc. The name of the directory and its subdirectory will never change, so they will always be called `Energy\Source` and `Energy\Archive`

How do I need to configure my paths to make sure they always get into the right location?

Comment: I don't think you can do better with `.ini` file format than split it out to a separate `driveLetter` option and split the `[Paths]` members to implicitly have the drive letter added in front of them.

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean? Can you show an example?

Comment: `driveletter = Q` and then use `source = \data\Energy\Source` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @tripleee suggestion, and assuming you have a way to know at runtime what the current drive letter is:

Create your config file like this (using *basic interpolation*)

```
[DEFAULT]
driveletter = X
[PATHS]
source = %(driveletter)s/data/Energy/Source
archive = %(driveletter)s/data/Energy/Archive
```

Read it, and change the default letter at runtime. Suppose you have a `newletter` variable set to "Z"

```
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read("myconfig.ini")
cfg["DEFAULT"]["driveletter"] = newletter
cfg["PATHS"]["source"]
'Z/uat/data/Energy/Source'
```

Comment: My runtime is every 5 minutes, does that mean I have to change my config file every 5 minutes....

Comment: I don't think your connection will change name every 5 minutes :) So your code just needs to check if the "old" connection letter is still valid, and if it's not then discover the current one (lots of Q/A here on that, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827371/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-available-windows-drives) ) and update the config file. No need for any manual update