# Accessing an image from storage of a plugged in Android phone, on Windows with Python

Tags: python, android, windows, mtp, usb-mass-storage

Using Python in Win10, I want to read a picture that is on the SD card of an Android phone. The phone is connected to the Windows computer via USB.

If the image is on the local hard drive, I can use

```
file = r'D:\0.png'
handle = open(file)
```

The directory for the file on the SD card as displayed in the Windows Explorer is

```
file = r'This PC\Redmi Note 11\SD-карта\0.png'
```

However, Python will not find the image in that directory. Note the Cyrillic 'карта'. Listing all available drives by Python ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/827371/12842085)) does not show the SD card or phone. What path definition should I use in Python to access the image from the SD card?

Comment: yes, opencv has trouble with unicode non-ascii characters in paths. however, here, the real problem is that not even Python's own `open()` can access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Start the investigation by figuring out [which drives are available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/827371/176769) on Windows as `"This PC"` is not a valid name when trying to access file programatically.

Next, print the root directories of that drive and slowly build a string that contains the full path to that image.

Comment: In the given link there are many methods but none of them shows the phone or SD card as a drive. Only the local drives of the computer are listed.

Comment: Why is it so hard to access the image?