# Get each partition information with Python

Tags: python, windows, diskspace

How do you get all partitions and their info (total space, free space etc.) with Python on Windows?
[Thi example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658/cross-platform-space-remaining-on-volume-using-python) shows how to get free space, but you must know partitions/folders... I would like to get info for all partitions (maybe except CD-ROMs).

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286534/) can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [WMI module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html). There are many recipes in the [WMI cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html), including

- Find Drive Types
- Show the percentage free space for each fixed disk
- Show disk partitions

Comment: Thanks, WMI looks pretty useful library

Comment: I am still in process of doing it by the way, does python WMI module has the ability to create partition?