# Listing physical drives installed on my computer

Tags: c++, windows, boost, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list physical disks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327718/how-to-list-physical-disks)

What is the "best way" (fastest) C++ way to List physical drives installed on my computer? Is there a boost library to do that?

Comment: So, only boost? what libraries are you allowed to use? what operating system?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER Windows is system I'm working on, boost is the preferred way but other in case boost doesn't do it will get accepted too.

Comment: "Drives" are not a cross-platform concept, so I doubt you're going to find a cross-platform solution to this. Just use the Windows API if you're targeting Windows.

Comment: @smallB - You could use `GetLogicalDrives()`, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286534/enumerating-all-available-drive-letters-in-windows

Comment: Please, specify target OS and what exactly do you need: logical drivers under Windows, partitions or physical drives.

Comment: File system is different concept than physical drive, even if it's closely related. As Boost:Filesystem doesn't deal with drives, you can't use it for that purpose. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/327718/11343) for a solution.

Comment: @volodymyr as I've answered 7 minutes before you asked me for it (see my reply to Mr. TAMER) the OS is Windows

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that. So I can propose you two possible solutions: You can use WMI classes or refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327718/how-to-list-physical-disks and use QueryDosDevice and GetLogicalDrives as it was mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 12):

use `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` to retrieve   all the available logical drives.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


DWORD mydrives = 100;// buffer length
char lpBuffer[100];// buffer for drive string storage

int main()
{
      DWORD test = GetLogicalDriveStrings( mydrives, lpBuffer);

      printf("The logical drives of this machine are:\n\n");

      for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)    printf("%c", lpBuffer[i]);


      printf("\n");
      return 0;
}
```

or use `GetLogicalDrives()`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// initial value
TCHAR szDrive[ ] = _T(" A:");

int main()
{
  DWORD uDriveMask = GetLogicalDrives();
  printf("The bitmask of the logical drives in hex: %0X\n", uDriveMask);
  printf("The bitmask of the logical drives in decimal: %d\n", uDriveMask);
  if(uDriveMask == 0)
      printf("\nGetLogicalDrives() failed with failure code: %d\n", GetLastError());
  else
  {
      printf("\nThis machine has the following logical drives:\n");
  while(uDriveMask)
    {// use the bitwise AND, 1–available, 0-not available
     if(uDriveMask & 1)
        printf("%s\n",szDrive);
     // increment... 
     ++szDrive[1];
      // shift the bitmask binary right
      uDriveMask >>= 1;
     }
    printf("\n ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use WMI to enumerate the instances of [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132.aspx).