# Name and number of partitions on a hard drive

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In windows programming, how can we find out the number of partitions and the name of each partition on the hard drive?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/286534/1250303.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contol code to get a list of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164038.aspx) on how to do this at MSDN. It utilizes the `GetLogicalDrives`, `GetLogicalDriveStrings`, `GetDriveType`, and `GetVolumeInformation` functions. You can [download the source from here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/6/2/76213996-928e-4adf-a068-ddc35a58fe35/CQA0401.exe).